# Transit Options exclude subaway not working Google Maps API

Tags: html, json, google-maps, http, postman

I'm using Google Maps API in order to get the route between two points using train.

Creating my request, I set `mode`:`transit`, and `transit_mode`:`train`

but, I'm still getting in the results `train+subways`.

Is it able to only get results excluding subway using API request and getting results only using Train?

Thank you.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJjwVTgEr-Lg0R9IcbIxjbFBk&destination=place_id:ChIJXTFiSx4qQg0RjqEcPSxC6Vw&mode=transit&language=es&alternatives=false&transit_mode=train&key=API_KEY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#optional-parameters), including `transit_mode=train` or `transit_mode=subway` only causes the API to *prefer* routing by that mode (which means it doesn't do what you want, which would be to exclude all other modes).

**transit_mode** — Specifies one or more preferred modes of transit. This parameter may only be specified for transit directions, and only if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID. The parameter supports the following arguments:

- **bus** indicates that the calculated route should prefer travel by bus.
- **subway** indicates that the calculated route should **prefer** travel by subway.
- **train** indicates that the calculated route should **prefer** travel by train
  ...

Comment: The question was focused in not only "prefer", and get only directions with transit_mode selected. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not according to the documentation.  If there are multiple results, you could ignore those you don't want.